# Ordering SQL statement in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a table called email from which I fetch email.
The table has email in this order

1. asda@gmaila.omc

   123@dsad.com
   name@gmail.com

Now If I make this query

```
SELECT * FROM email WHERE (email IN ( 'asda@gmaila.omc' ,'123@dsad.com' ,  'name@gmail.com' )) AND email!='' LIMIT 3
```

I get this

123@dsad.com

asda@gmaila.omc

name@gmail.com

but I want to get result on the basis of the arguments in the `IN clause`
If you notice in the `IN` I mentioned `asda@gmaila.omc` first,
I dont think order by clause will help me here
Any other way of solving this issue?

Comment: **The table has enail in this order** Do you possibly have a RowID, Or TimeStamp? What do you order it by?

Comment: @astander it has time stamp and row ID both , but I want to order on the basis of the arguments I supplied in the IN statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible approach is using [**FIELD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) MySQL function:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM email
    WHERE FIELD(email, 'asda@gmaila.omc', '123@dsad.com', 'name@gmail.com') <> 0 
 ORDER BY FIELD(email, 'asda@gmaila.omc', '123@dsad.com', 'name@gmail.com');
```

As `FIELD` returns 0 if its first argument isn't equal to any other, `FIELD(str, 'aaa', 'bbb'...) <> 0` clause is roughly equivalent to `str IN ('aaa', 'bbb')`.

Comment: @raina660w where is the IN and where clause now?

Comment: It was in `LIMIT` actually, have you checked it?

Comment: the updated answer works, what does <> 0 do? I know <> is equal to !=

Comment: Updated the answer once again with an explanation. ) In short, `FIELD` is used both for ordering (obviously) and for filtering out the unwanted strings from the result set (in the previous edition I've done the same with `LIMIT 3` clause).

Comment: Curious if `FIELD` will use an index on the `email` column, or if this amounts to a seq. scan.

Comment: Judging from [this demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65495/4), it does. Still I admit I'm not sure that `FIELD` result is cached here; if it's not, using `email IN(...)` should be better performance-wise.